# combinations of how to buy items

Tags: c++, algorithm, combinations

I'm trying to find a way to figure out (in c++), given a list of items with a constant price, how many ways a person can buy X amount of items if they have X amount of dollars.

So far, I have attempted to use nested for loops to try and brute force a solution, however, I feel i might be missing a very simple solution that I can't seem to see.

Any help would be very much appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: Can they only buy item a X times with Z dollars OR can they buy item a X times, item b Y times, ... with Z dollars

Comment: [Knapsack problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem)

Comment: X items with X dollars is the requirement. so for example they must buy 10 items that equal to 10 dollars.

Comment: Assuming there are Y different types of item. Each item has a price less than a dollar. Then you can do this Y! times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is very similar to the common programming question: "How many ways can you combine Y types of coins with Z values to make X dollars", i.e. make change for X dollars with Y coin types.

Here's a general solution that could be ported to C++:

```
I = list of items SORTED from highest to lowest price
N = number of items bought so far
M = money left
S = money to start

function shop(I, N, M, S):
  if M < 0: return 0 //we bought something illegally! 
  if M == 0:
    //If we have no money, we've bought all we could. 
    //Check our condition that num items N = starting money S
    return 1 if N == S, else 0 
  if I is empty:
    return 0 //no more item combos, no way to buy things.
  else:
    newI = I with first element removed 
    //Every time we want to buy stuff, we have two options: 
    //1. buy something of highest value and subtract money
    //2. Shop ignoring the next highest value item
    return shop(newI, N, M, S) + shop(I, N+1, M-(cost of first item), S)
```

With X dollars, you start off with the call:

```
shop(I, 0, X, X)
```